Leaflet Side Panel <div> position
I am working on this page with a map.
I use the Leaflet SidePanel plugin, which should place a tab in the map.
As you can see, the SidePanel  appears outside the map, at the bottom of the page.
I have followed the given instructions  and I can't see where the problem is.
